# Set MAC address to default

Tags: mac-address

Sometimes I need to spoof MAC address, I'm doing so with this command:

```
ip link set dev eth0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Is there a way how to set MAC address back to default without reboot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See also:

```
sudo ethtool -P eth0
```

So, to set the MAC address back to its default (assuming GNU grep here):

```
set_to_real() (
  for i do
    mac=$(ethtool -P "$i" | grep -iEom1 '([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2}') &&
      ip link set dev "$i" address "$mac"
  done
)
set_real eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "real MAC" might be reported by the kernel on boot, so have a look at

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

and try using your `ip link set...` with the MAC you find there.

Comment: Well, I was looking for something else (like eth0 address "set-to-real") but this is also a solution, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a *macchanger* tool which allows to do it. From `man macchanger`:

```
macchanger [options] device
 -p, --permanent
     Reset MAC address to its original, permanent hardware value.
```

So assuming your interface is *eth0*, you run:
`# macchanger -p eth0`